# Getting 'value' property from a DOM element not visible in the page using Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm using Playwright and have a bunch of element values I need to assert which I can currently only get by clicking on an edit button to enter an iFrame upon which the value is visible (can be searched for and found in Chrome Dev tools)

I wonder if I can get around this without the effort of opening and closing the relevant iFrame each time, because these values DO exist under the 'value' property under the Chrome dev tools 'properties' tab.

If I do this:

```
const aHandle = await this.page.evaluateHandle(() => document.body);
const resultHandle = await this.page.evaluateHandle(body => body.innerHTML, aHandle);
console.log(await resultHandle.jsonValue());
await resultHandle.dispose();
```

...then the logged output does not have the value I am trying to access, no doubt because I'm using the 'body.innerText()' method and this isn't innertext but there is no 'getProperty()' method on 'body'

The selector which correctly targets the field and shows the value ONLY in the properties tab is:

```
#Manufacturer > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.stb-rich-text-fields > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > textarea
```

This fails:

```
let manufacturer
const handle = await this.page.evaluateHandle(() => ({window, document}));
const properties = await handle.getProperties();
manufacturer = await this.page.locator(this.elements.manufacturer); //selector as per above
manufacturer = await handle.getProperty('value')
```

I have a feeling this can be achieved, any help appreciated.

Comment: If the expected behavior is - text being visible  only after edit button is clicked, why are you trying to find without clicking it ?

Comment: Assuming you are asserting something in an typical web application.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal thanks for the responses.  It's not a typical web application in so much as it is a very old UI so is difficult to automate. 

I'm trying to find without clicking as my intention is to assert data in a database is correctly represented in the UI and not replicating the user experience as such

Answer (score 0):

***Resolved***
This utility function works:

```
 async getValueFromValue(locator: string): Promise<string> {
 const elementHandle = await this.page.locator(locator);
 const valueHandle = await 
 elementHandle.evaluateHandle((element) => element.value);
 return valueHandle.jsonValue();
}
```